# AngularJS select drop-down not RED per required

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, select, drop-down-menu

I have a required field that works great. I have it with the tag "required" such that every time the screen initializes then that field will have a red outline around the box. It's a select with (s) and the red outline works during initialization.  However, once i discard some changes and make the field null or empty string (i.e. field = "") the red outline disappears.  Why is that?

Here is some HTML:

```
Status: <select ng-model="customerStatus" data-z-required required>
                            <option></option>
                            <option value="A">Active</option>
                            <option value="L">Lapsed</option>
                            <option value="P">Pending</option>
                            <option value="I">Inactive</option>
                        </select>
```

In my controller i simply set customerStatus = null or customerStatus = "" and neither gives me a red border. In fact, it's actually the CAUSE for the red border to disappear. How can i get that red box back and clear out any values in the field?

Comment: are you using a form? are you using `novalidate` ? Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: I am using a form but not "novalidate".

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle of your form?

Comment: No, sorry. It's way to big to fit into a fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

After you have cleared the values in the form you can call $setPristine().  This will set the value of the form back $pristine.  The total call will look like $scope.nameoftheform.$setPristine()

Comment: $pristine will set the state of the form back to its original state.  Are you using ng-form or html form tag on your page.  Or are you just using a select box?